# Reconstruct/Cache google map with tiles for offline personal use

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css, google-maps

im going to drive my car to some inhabitable place where there is no internet and without a good map It would be dangerous. I would like to have google map with me all the time, but problem = it's not cache-able.

Therefore I need to put these image tile on my laptop, and maybe use iphone/laptop to view it.

I have started with download the some of map tiles into harddrive with my own filename, for example:

`gmap_z12_x234_y434.png` is a google map zoom level 12, x=234 y=434, 256x256 pixel tiles.

I have also roughly worked out the **Mercator map projection**. (i.e. given a GPS geo coordinate, I know which tile and it's neighbor to pickup)

Question (javascript + HTML + css way):
How do I reconstruct a webpage view? that can have the functionality like google maps? (zoom in/out, drag, pan ...) 
Should I do my own js, html and css stuff? openlayers support this?
Has another done it before? 
Answer any question will be very helpful for me, thanks in advance!

Comment: "inhabitable place where there is no internet and without a good map It would be dangerous" - We're assuming this is hypothetical?

Comment: well, some desert? middle of nowhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The licensing terms for Google Maps forbid local caching. I'd recommend openstreetmap.org as an alternative and in particular the oMaps iPhone application, if you have such a device. It has excellent offline support.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to reconstruct these tiles into a webpage? any library?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. However it is at least legal to use the OSM images offline and there's a ton of open source development tools available. Have a look at their wiki or maybe ask on their mailing lists/irc channels.